# Power query data load into model and table does not sort correctly

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a table that I fetch via a connect through Power Query, which has a list of names. I apply some steps including sorting the names column alphabetically and then loading it to a Table and the "Data Model". However the table that is loaded onto a worksheet contains the list of the names sorted in a completely different order, its like Excel is ignoring my sorting preference completely. I tried to sort the data in the "Data Model" resorting it in Power query even the table in the worksheet itself, but after I hit refresh it reverts to the wrong order.

Answer (score 2):

Try Table.Buffer wrapped around the sort

```
= Table.Buffer(Table.Sort(Source,{{"date", Order.Ascending}}))
```

or, alternatively, add an index at start, and resort on index when done

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm buffering doesn't work.  Incredible bug.